# 404 graphic is mis-aligned on main site

Tags: bug, design

Edit: **This was fixed on both sites and now seems to happen randomly.**

On Chrome, the portal 404 graphic is misaligned with the not found text. I'm pretty sure this is a bug not a design decision. The same thing happens on the regular site. Here is the webpage I get:

[image: Misaligned image]

To show what it should look like, here is a comparison for the [English](http://english.stackexchange.com) SE site: 
[image: Aligned image]

Comment: status-norepro for me, unless a fix was already pushed: http://i.stack.imgur.com/x9Y20.png Chrome 35/Windows 8

Comment: @JohnB It's still broken for me. I'm using Windows 7. Chrome 35.

Comment: Hmm, I booted up a Win7 machine and still wasn't able to reproduce this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kTuob.png Are there any extensions you have installed that might be causing some strange behavior?

Comment: I confirm Milo's misalignment claims. Windows 7, Chrome 35.

Comment: @JohnB I disabled all extensions by opening a new incognito window and I am still experiencing the bug.

Comment: @JohnB It seemed to have fixed itself. This should now be status-completed.

Comment: @JohnB It's misaligned in **all** Macintosh browsers (Chrome/Safari/Firefox)... so... not completed?

Comment: @Scott I can confirm it is still messed up.

Comment: I've been noticing the same thing...

Comment: I can confirm this with Opera as well as Firefox.